# In what sense is Constant Applicative Form applicative?

Tags: haskell

I understand a CAF is a *form* in a sense of it being of specific shape in memory, or one of infinitely many possible *graphic* representations of some value it can be *evaluated* to. ([It is noted](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects#Thunks) that "constant applicative form" is synonymous to "static thunk".)

I understand it being *constant* in that there are *no free variables* and all the information necessary to evaluate a Constant Form is already contained therein. It's a shape that has no arrows pointing outwards.

But why "*applicative*"? I can't sleep at night due to this. Everyone says caf, caf, but who actually knows what that literally means? Does it have something to do with applicative functors (I guess not)? What other kinds of applicative forms does one get out there?

Comment: I'm really rather sure it has nothing directly to do with applicative functors, but what it _has_ to do with I do not know.

Comment: I think "applicative" here relates to function application, not applicative functors. Beyond that, I'm not sure why CAF has "applicative" in the name (especially since not all CAFs are function values).

Comment: I also assumed the first two words had the sense of "constant application", as in all the application in the syntactic(?) form occurs on constant values (CAFs themselves?), in contrast to a closure. Am I right to call it a "syntactic" notion? It seems you can decide a thing is a CAF by understanding scoping

Answer (score 3):

A term in constant applicative form is a constant applied to (zero or more) other constants. (Of course each of those constants may require quite some computation before they're fully evaluated!)

Comment: I think I kind of understand what you mean, but I think the answer is not very clear. Maybe you could elaborate on the notion of terms, constants and what applies to what?

As I understand from your post, a thing may be applicative in a sense that it can at any time be applied. Then it has to not be nullary, thus, say, `(+)` is a binary caf, `(+1)` is an unary caf, but then `(1+1)` is a CF, but not caf, because it cannot anymore be applied. In other words: is an expression that evaluates to `2` still an applicative thing?

Comment: @Kindaro No, as I explicitly call out in my answer, a thing does not have to "not be nullary" to be considered a CAF; and also your example is not nullary, so wouldn't even be a counterexample if that were a rule! `1+1` is the constant `(+)` applied to the (zero or more) other constants `1` and `1`. Even the fully-evaluated form of this, namely `2`, which *is* nullary, is a CAF, because it is the constant `2` applied to zero other constants. ALSO: my answer was not intended to be a definition, so I did not try to be precise; it was intended instead to be a motivation for the choice of terms.

Comment: @Kindaro And in particular I haven't given a precise definition of constant because I don't know what it is, as I detailed in my first comment on 0xd34df00d's answer. The standard definition appears not to match with the examples typically given of what a CAF is. I even went and looked in SPJ's Implementation of Functional Programming Languages, supposedly the canonical source, where they also give a definition mentioning the lack of free variables but give examples that include free variables. So I have to admit I'm a bit confused about that point myself!

Answer (score 1):

Every CAF is a supercombinator, and supercombinators are, long story short, functions that take other (possibly nullary) functions and *apply* them to one another.

So, my understanding of "applicative" in the CAF name is as referring to their supercombinatorish nature.

Comment: Hm. Supercombinators have no free variables, right? But I would certainly consider, say, `foo = M.fromList [(3,4),(5,6)]` a CAF, even though it mentions many free variables (notably and unarguably `M.fromList`; with more argument `(,)`, `(:)`, and `[]`; to a lesser extent also `fromInteger`; unclear to me the status of the number literals themselves).

Comment: That requires a better formalization what a free variable is. Your `foo` (or, better say, everything to the right of `=`) is a CAF, since `M.fromList` and all other entities you mentioned are not really free variables, but rather references to other CAFs. A free variable would be `x` in `foo x = ... where theMap = M.fromList [(3, 4), (5, 6), (x, x)]`. Things get a bit more subtle with type classes, but that's probably out of scope of the comment space.

Comment: @DanielWagner It looks like it can have function applications where the function names are a free variables (I'm guessing there's a restriction that they are top-level). The [Haskell wiki mentions that partially applied functions count as CAFs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form). Otherwise, I think the only CAFs you *could* have would be lambdas applied to other lambdas (since the CAF cannot itself be a lambda expression), which doesn't seem to fit the examples I've seen.

Comment: @0xd34df00d I would guess that most functions that `M.fromList` could refer to are not CAFs (since a lot of them probably have the form `fromList xs = ...`, rather than directly being a partial application of a function or just a direct combination of other CAFs with no outer lambda).

Comment: @DavidYoung now that I think of it, a CAF is a supecombinator that has no free variables. So if a CAF refers to a supercombinator that is not a CAF, it doesn't cancel out its CAFness.

Comment: @0xd34df00d That makes sense. It seems like you might need a slightly less common (I think) definition of "free variable" where top-level definition names wouldn't count as free variables though, right?

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Haskell Cafe and Stephen Tetley [kindly clarified](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2018-January/128508.html) this for me. Briefly:

> Circa the 1970s and 80s "applicative" was often used in the UK as a
>   synonym for functional ...

-- So we may kind of paraphrase the "caf" as "cff".

I will still have to be looking into what this actually means. Stephen suggested a [paper](http://thecorememory.com/Next_700.pdf) that talks, among other things, of *applicative expressions* which may happen to be the same thing as our applicative forms, but it will take indefinite time for me to get through to making a reasonably well founded statement of whether it is the case, so I will post an answer for now, while  reserving for the possibility of my expanding it after a while.